# Use VB.NET public (global) variable in XAML

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a variable in Universal.vb module in my Windows Store App (Windows 8/8.1).

```
Public TestMaze As Boolean = (GtSt("MazeOn", 0) = 1)
```

I want to use TestMaze in a XAML page to turn on/off a ToggleButton. The code looks like this:

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="chkMaze" IsOn={StaticResource TestMaze}"/>
```

What is the right method to do it?

PS: I do not want to do it on Loaded event of the page because it cause an impulse flicker in ToggleButton.
PS2: GtSt is a function I defined for quicker access for RoamingSettings.

```
Public Function GtSt(SettingName As String, Optional DefaultVal As Double = 0) As Double
    Dim ProgSet = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings
    If Not ProgSet.Values.ContainsKey(SettingName) Then
        SvSt(SettingName, DefaultVal)
    End If
    GtSt = ProgSet.Values(SettingName)
End Function
```

Comment: The redundant department of redundancy called, they want their `If(condition, True, False)` back. Just write `condition`.

Comment: Oops! hahaha.
My bad. I don't appreciate redundancy neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved my goal by writing

```
chkMaze.IsOn = TestMaze
```

on the SizeChanged event of the page. I didn't knew SizeChanged occurs before Loaded.